# log4j2 RollingFileAppender CronTriggeringPolicy throws NoSuchFileException

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I use log4j2 2.7 version and
I have log4j2 configured appender that should roll over every minute:

```
<Appenders>
    <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
    </Console>
    <RollingFile name="File" fileName="C://api.log"
                 filePattern="C://ssvp-api.log//api.%d{yyyyMMdd.HHmm}.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB"/>
            <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0/1 * * * ?"/>
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>

</Appenders>
```

But for some unknown reasons I receive the following exceptions during logs rollover:

```
2018-06-06 14:52:00,018 Log4j2-TF-3-Scheduled-1 ERROR Unable to move file C:\api.20180606.1448.log to C:\api.20180606.1448.log: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException C:\api.20180606.1448.log -> C:\api.20180606.1448.log
2018-06-06 14:52:00,019 Log4j2-TF-3-Scheduled-1 ERROR Unable to copy file C:\api.20180606.1448.log to C:\api.20180606.1448.log: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException C:\api.20180606.1448.log
```

But if I update my filePattern with %i to *C://ssvp-api.log//api.%d{yyyyMMdd.HHmm}-%i.log* everything works fine, but I don't want to have additional file number in my log files name (for ex. api.20180606.1448-1.log)

Is there any chance to avoid having file number in the log file name?

Comment: Try adding 1 expression for odd minutes and other for even ones: `<CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 */2 * * * ?"/>`, for odd minutes `<CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 1-59/2 * * * ?"/>`. Based on [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/220006/how-to-1-cron-job-every-odd-minutes-and-1-other-every-even-minutes).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found out  that log4j2 2.7 version contains a couple issues related to CronTriggeringPolicy functionality, they are:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1487
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1640
Update to 2.8.1 version solved my problem.